# How to count between two MySQL tables using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, how can I count how many times the tag HTML is displayed in the `a_id` column and then display all the tags that are related to the `a_id` column in alphabetical order.

Here is the MySQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE a_tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
a_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here is whats in the MySQL tables

```
TABLE tags
id      tag
1       HTML
2       HTML
3       CSS
4       PHP
5       HTML

TABLE a_tags
id      tag_id      a_id
1       1           3
2       2           2
3       3           3
4       4           3
5       5           3
```

And Here is the code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a_tags.*, tags.* 
                       FROM a_tags 
                       INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = a_tags.tag_id 
                       WHERE a_tags.users_a_id=3
                       ORDER BY users_a_id DESC");
```

Comment: yes read on I hoped explained it right.

Answer (score 0):

Woudln't

```
SELECT * FROM `a_tags` WHERE a_id = (SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag` = 'HTML')
```

work?

Edit:  This might not be what you want it to do.  If you could clarify your question, it'd be helpful.

Comment: I want all the tags that are related to `a_id` not just the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see what the foreign keys are but assuming that a_tags.a_id maps to tags.id then try this.

```
SELECT tags.tag,COUNT(a_tags.a_id) FROM a_tags
JOIN tags ON a_tags.a_id = tags.id
GROUP BY a_tags.a_id
```